# Can this for loop code(with an `if not in` condition) be converted to list comprehension?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, python-3.7

How can this code be converted to a list comprehension?

```
pangram = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
lst = []
for char in pangram.casefold():
    if char not in lst:
        lst.append(char)
lst.sort()
print(''.join(lst))
```

I tried the following list comprehension but it is not working:

```
lst = [char for char in pangram.casefold if char not in lst]
```

It gives the following error

```
NameError: name 'lst' is not defined
```

Please suggest a solution.

Comment: Is there a reason why you do not use a ``set``? Do you need the initial ordering? A ``set`` will automatically reject duplicates, and can also be written as a comprehension. In this case, just ``set(pangram)`` is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for either a list or a comprehension. Use a `set` to automatically eliminate duplicates.

```
>>> pangram = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
>>> letters = set(pangram.casefold())  # the unique letters in pangram
>>> ''.join(sorted(letters))
' abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
```

---

In principle, the `for` loop can be converted to a list comprehension. This works by using a second `set` or `list` and exploiting that `lst.append`/`set.add` returns `None`, which allows evaluating a second expression when used with `or`.

```
>>> pangram = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
>>> seen = set()
>>> lst = [seen.add(char) or char for char in pangram.casefold() if char not in seen]
>>> lst.sort()
>>> ' abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
```

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to hack it with a list comprehension but you'll have to pre-define `lst` first:

```
In [1]: pangram = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"                                                         
In [2]: lst = []                                                                                                        
In [3]: [lst.append(char) for char in pangram.casefold() if char not in lst] 
In [5]: lst.sort()                                                                                                      
In [6]: print(''.join(lst))                                                                                             
 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

But, this is really **NOT** a good practice because list comprehensions are meant for **creating lists**, not for mutating an existing one. In this solution, you are actually creating a list of `None`'s because `.append()` returns `None`.

If the goal is just to get the unique values **and** order is not important, use a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) instead. (I assume order is not important because you `sort` it after).

```
In [29]: pangram = "aAaabBBbbcCc"                                                                                       

In [30]: lst = list(set(pangram.casefold()))                                                                            
In [31]: lst.sort()                                                                                                     
In [32]: print(''.join(lst))                                                                                            
abc

In [33]: lst = []                                                                                                       
In [34]: [lst.append(char) for char in pangram.casefold() if char not in lst]                                           
Out[34]: [None, None, None]
In [35]: lst.sort()                                                                                                     
In [36]: print(''.join(lst))                                                                                            
abc
```

Answer (score 0):

One liner could be:

`"".join([letter for letter in sorted(set(pangram.casefold()))])`

Comment: I was trying a list comprehension

Comment: @VayunEkbote Updated the answer, does that solve your problem ?